# iOS Safari not accepting 3rd party cookie

Tags: iphone, ios, cookies, mobile-safari

I have a webservice that adds a cookie to the Http Response.  The request can sometimes be cross domain.  Ive been finding articles saying iOS safari currently blocks 3rd party cookie by default (having the "Accept Cookies" option set to "sites i visited").

When testing on our server (domain.com), and performing a request to our service cross domain (tracker.domain.com), it works fine (even if we clear out all our cookies first).  But we have given the webservice to a customer with the same setup (html page is on domain.com, the request to our service is made to customer.domain.com), a new session is created with each request.  The customers server has the correct p3p policy set for the headers in IIS7 for both servers.

Why the selective blocking?

Comment: In both cases, does the subdomain share the root domain of the main domain (subdomain.domain.com and domain.com)? Or is there a little variation between your setup and the customer's?